# Using Numpy's PyArray_IsScalar in Cython

Tags: numpy, cython

TLDR: How can I define the `is_float_object` function below in pure cython?

I'm trying to understand a few functions in `pandas._libs` that are defined in [pandas/_libs/src/numpy_helper.h](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/src/numpy_helper.h) and exposed via [pandas/_libs/src/util.pxd](http://pandas/_libs/src/util.pxd).  AFAICT my confusion is related to having no intuition for namespaces in the `.h` file.

Take `is_float_object` as an example.  This is defined in `numpy_helper.h` as

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
#include "numpy/arrayscalars.h"
[...]

PANDAS_INLINE int is_float_object(PyObject* obj) {
    return (PyFloat_Check(obj) || PyArray_IsScalar(obj, Floating));
}
```

I can't figure out where `Floating` is defined, how it got into the namespace, and what type of `cdef extern from ...` I need to use to get it into a cython file.

`PyArray_IsScalar` is defined in [numpy/ndarrayobject.h](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h#L49):

```
#define PyArray_IsScalar(obj, cls)                                        \
    (PyObject_TypeCheck(obj, &Py##cls##ArrType_Type))
```

There is a comment in pandas/_libs/src/numpy.pxd that makes me think the "##" means some special magic is at play:

```
# Cannot be supported due to ## ## in macro:
# bint PyArray_IsScalar(object, verbatim work)
```

Where is `Floating` defined?  What would it take to define this function directly in cython without needing the intermediate `numpy_helper.h` file?

Answer (score 3):

`##` is a C preprocessor concatenation. `Floating` isn't in any namespace but is just used in a string concatenation by the C preprocessor. The section `PyArray_IsScalar(obj, Floating)` is translated by the C preprocessor to be:

```
(PyObject_TypeCheck(obj, &PyFloatingArrType_Type))
```

If you want to define the `is_float_object` in Cython you'd do this concatenation yourself:

```
from cpython cimport PyFloat_Check, PyObject_TypeCheck, PyTypeObject

cdef extern from "numpy/arrayobject.h":
   PyTypeObject PyFloatingArrType_Type

cdef int is_float_object(obj):
    return (PyFloat_Check(obj) or (PyObject_TypeCheck(obj, &PyFloatingArrType_Type)));
```

(the `cdef extern from "numpy/arrayobject.h"` is a bit of a guess, but I think it comes from there)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this.  I've got some more permutations to try, but so far this is leading to segfaults.  It seems like it isn't checking to see if PyFloatingArrType_Type exists until actually trying to call the function.  That seems like the opposite of what I would expect a compile language to do.  Am I interpreting that incorrectly?

Comment: It looks like ndarrayobject.h #includes __multiarray_api.h, which labels PyFloatingArrType_Type with NPY_NO_EXPORT.  I'm guessing this means I'm out of luck.  https://github.com/explosion/thinc/blob/master/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h#L112

Comment: I suspect you need to run `numpy.import_array()` first. `PyFloatingArrType_Type` is most likely a global variable which is only initialized by the module import code. It exists at compile-time but doesn't have a valid value until initialized.

Comment: I don't think `NPY_NO_EXPORT` is a massive problem - it probably isn't best practice to use it, but given that pandas does you know that it does work

Comment: np.import_array() did the trick.  You've done your good deed for the day.